# how can I use a Request.Form() on a windows application?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have written a HTTP server in VB.NET but I don't know how to use the Request.Form() method on a windows application. I need it to read HTML data sent in a HTML form. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have valid HttpContext, just add reference to `System.Web` assembly in your project, then have such code:

```
Dim value As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form("mykey")
```

Comment: Thanks. lemmi try n c whether its gonna work I'll get back to you.\

Comment: lol, took you four years to try - guess it's never too late! ;-)